# How can I iterate through normal array in karate?

Tags: karate

Output of one of my tasks is coming as ['a','b','c']

Now I have to use these values in a DB query

```
* def queryToGetHotelIdForAvailableCsId = "select id from hotels_hotel where cs_id in ('a','b','c');"
```

How can I do this in karate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to use a Java helper, but here you go:

```
* def json = ['a', 'b', 'c']
* def fun = 
"""
function(array) {
  var temp = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) temp = temp + ',';
    temp = temp + "'" + array[i] + "'"
  }
  return '(' + temp + ')';
}
"""
* def result = fun(json)
* match result == "('a','b','c')"
```